# Change root directory of WebSphere Application Server Traditional ND V9

Tags: websphere

We had successfully installed a WAS ND to a few servers and setup the clustering, installed with test app and working fine. Server are RHEL7.

The WAS was installed in the default directory `/opt/IBM/WebSphere` but due to administration purpose, we are required to move them into `/app` instead.

Is there any definitive guide or steps that we need to follow to move the installation? Would prefer not to delete everything and perform from scratch if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a recent fix pack (less than a year old, so like 9.0.0.4 but the newer the better) on your 9.0 install, you could install 9.0 to the desired install location, create blank profiles with the same cell and node names as your current profiles, and use the migration tools to clone your profiles into the new install which will handle updating all the paths in the profiles.

To do so you would follow the [instructions for migrating your profiles to new versions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.migration.nd.doc/ae/tmig_migrate_cells_commandline.html), but would need to specify `-allowSameRelease true` to the `WASPreUpgrade` command, as well as `-clone true` to both `WASPreUpgrade` and `WASPostUpgrade`. Federated nodes you'll need to feed in the `-newDmgrHostname` and `-newDmgrSoapPort` to `WASPostUpgrade` as well. If you intend to keep the same ports, you should shut the old deployment manager down beforehand so the migration process doesn't try to contact it instead.

It could also be possible to use `mangeprofiles -backupProfile` and `manageprofiles -restoreProfile` to just move the profiles over, but after that you'll have to search for any instances of the old install location in the profile config and correct it to the new path yourself--it won't translate the paths for you. I haven't tried it so I can't vouch for that one.